# Late this week/month/year

Tags: grammaticality, adjective-phrases, alternatives

To my knowledge, ***'late'*** can be placed in front of time period terms (day/week/month/year) to indicate the final part of a duration. However, there are a number of constructions (especially ones involving the present time period as opposed to past or future) that are open to my personal doubt, mostly due to the lack of search results for instances of their usage. Are the ***'late-phrases'*** in the list below correct and natural English? If not, how can I reword them to express the same idea?

> 1. There will be a movie in here late tomorrow.
> 2. I will be starting university late this year.
> 3. We will expect a sudden temperature drop late this month.
> 4. He will arrive late today

Many thanks in advance.

Comment: @DavidWashington 1. We would never say _"There will be a movie **in** here tomorrow evening."_ The _in_ is not idiomatic. 2. We would never say _" I will be starting Uni **after fall** this year."_ You might hear _after **the** fall._ 3. In AmE, we don't use _uni_ as an abbreviation for university.

Comment: @P.E.Dant, #1 my mistake, I was lazy. I simply copied the op's sentence and changed the time adv. For #2, what about these two: "Steel demand set for 2010 rebound after fall this year", "Apple iPad mini 2 will probably hit the shelves after fall this year" ? #3, the uni. appears on unbandictionary, "I'm got classes at uni this afternoon", some people liked it some people didn't, but as long as we understand what the OP wanted to say, I think it is acceptable (in this question only).

Comment: @DavidWashington _"Steel demand set for 2010 rebound after fall this year"_ et al. are **headlinese**, and do not reflect actual usage. Try a search on this site for the term. _Uni_ is a BrE idiom, almost never heard elsewhere.

Comment: Thanks for your exchange of views. I see that some of my example sentences aren't as correct as they could be. I'd just like to point out that 'uni' is actually a pretty common abbreviation where I live, but it's interest to learn the divide. Also, why is 'in here' non-idiomatic? I have definitely heard it being used by native speakers before. How would you suggest I reword my first example sentence?

Comment: @P.E.Dant To make my first sentence sound natural, do I just have to drop the 'in', or should the whole thing be rephrased?

Comment: Without _in,_ it could be idiomatic in the right circumstances.

Comment: _"There will be a movie shown late tomorrow here in the auditorium."_

Comment: @JUNCINATOR, "I'd just like to point out that 'uni' is actually a pretty common abbreviation where I live...", we understand it.

Comment: JUNCINATOR, I am sorry for my mistake in the 2nd sentence. @P.E.Dant has corrected my mistake, it should be "the fall this year".

Comment: @David Washington, no problem mate. If you didn't bring it up I wouldn't have learned something new.

Comment: @P.E.Dant I have one last question on this subject. Is 'in here' incorrect in general or just in the context of my example sentence? If I open a box, only to find nothing inside, would it be idiomatic to say 'there is nothing in here!'?

Comment: Yes, that might be idiomatic, although it would be more common to hear simply _"There's nothing here!"_

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> There will be a movie in here **late** tomorrow.

better might be

> There will be a movie ***shown*** **late** tomorrow.
>   *There will be a movie shown tomorrow evening*.

Interesting ambiguity in your second sentence

> I will be starting Uni **late** this year.
>   *Uni will have already started by the time I get there.*

> I will be starting Uni **later** this year.
>   *I will be starting Uni in the fall.*

> We will expect a sudden temperature drop **late** this month.
>   *We will expect a sudden temperature drop at towards end of the month.*

Your last sentence is interesting in the same way the second sentence is

> He will arrive **late** today.
>   *He is coming today, but will be late (whenever he arrives)*.
>
> He will arrive **later** today.
>   *He will arrive in the evening today.*

Comment: Thanks for the answer. However, does this means none of my example sentences are correct though? You did provide alternatives but did not leave an assessment of whether the existing late-phrases in each of my sentence is idiomatic.